# How to post restricted access form in JMeter

Tags: forms, spring-security, jmeter

Using JMeter, I want to test the page. After fill in and submit the form, some insert into database is performed (adding new trip).

```
Path: /ProjectName/admin/addTrip.html
Method: POST
Parameters:
basePrice 500.0
hotelId 2
description Some text
```

The main issue is that the page is available after log in. And I don't know how to log in with `j_spring_security_check` using JMeter.

I tried to use Login Config Element as the parent of `HTTP Request` to addTrip page. As the result in `View Result Tree -> Response data` I get the login form. Of course this is not expected result.

Next I tried to use `HTTP Request` to login page.

```
Path: /ProjectName/j_spring_security_check
Method: POST
Parameters:
j_password mypassword
j_login mylogin
```

The result seems to be fine. `View Result Tree -> Response data` shows the correct (after login) page.
On the same level in thread group I added `Http Request` of addTrip. The result is the same as in the previous case - login page. No after addTrip page and no insert to database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your plan must be missing:

- cookie manager

And you probably didn't handle right the spring security login phase which includes redirect.

The best solution for you is to use [JMeter Proxy Recording](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf).
If you're a beginner in JMeter read:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html

Then for each component you will use you can read:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html

Comment: Your answer was somewhat helpful because in your links I found info about URL Re-writing Modifier. Point for you.